# QGIS plugin: are project variables creatable and writable

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qt, development

I like to develop a plugin and made a github [repository](https://github.com/CaptainAhab1982/variable_editor).
Upfront: this is my first time and haven't got a clue yet.

This is my target:

```
 This plugin is intended to be used in QGIS.
 QGIS has the ability to create and store variables that are specific to the software in 
 general, a loaded project or a specific datalayer in a project. These variables can be 
 called upon on in all sorts of algorithm and expressions.

 TARGET:
 The intended purpose of this plugin is to read a UI file when it is first used.
 The plugin should read the amount of inputfields in the UI file.
 It should add the same amount of projectvariables to the QGIS project and name them in a 
 similar way they are named in the UI. 

 Everytime the QGIS-project is opened the plugin should read the variables-values and 
 display them when the plugin is loaded. So the QGIS user doesn't need to set all the values 
 on project startup, instead the plugin uses the last know values.

 The intend of this project is to make a plugin that is easily changeable to the end-users 
 needs.
```

Why this plugin:
I, and probaly more users, have a goto project file in which work is done.
I have setup this project with 3 types of layers:
- Baselayers, which contain the skin of the earth.
- Informationlayers, which contain features on the earth.
- Worklayers, layers where work is done, using the base- and informationlayers.

This plugin helps me augment the symbology of the base- and informationlayers in a cental and easy-to-use place. At the moment i use a referencelayer (a .csv file) in which i store values, that are called upon by the symbology and labels of the base- and information layers.
The idea is to use the project variables instead of the values in the .csv file and use the plugin to change the values of the variables.

Example, this is the way I control the color of depthareas in my project with an expression:

```
CASE
-- green areas that are dry at LAT
WHEN DRVAL1 < '0' THEN '#84CC93'
-- Darkblue areas between LAT and the shallow contour
WHEN DRVAL1 < attribute(get_feature('chart- 
symbology_reference','value_type','Shallow'),'decimals') AND DRVAL2 > '0' THEN '#83BCE6'
-- blue areas between the shallow contour and safety contour
WHEN DRVAL1 < attribute(get_feature('chart- 
symbology_reference','value_type','Safety'),'decimals') AND DRVAL2 > 
attribute(get_feature('chart-symbology_reference','value_type','Shallow'),'decimals') THEN 
'#A4E1EC'
-- lightblue areas between the safety contour en deep contour
WHEN DRVAL1 < attribute(get_feature('chart- 
symbology_reference','value_type','Deep'),'decimals') AND DRVAL2 > 
attribute(get_feature('chart-symbology_reference','value_type','Safety'),'decimals') THEN 
'#AFF2DD'
-- verylightblue areas between the deep contour and infinite depth
WHEN DRVAL1 < '1000' AND DRVAL2 > attribute(get_feature('chart- 
symbology_reference','value_type','Deep'),'decimals') THEN '#FFFFFF'
END
```

Instead of the "attribute(get_feature('chart_sym....." i would like to reference to a project variable, and control the value of the projectvariable with a GUI.

I have made an UI file in QT 5 Designer:
[image]

In this case the plugin should create 15 variables in the project.
The names of the variables should be similar to the name of the input in the UI.
But a different user, should be able to upload a different UI-file, which then creates the right amount of projectvariables that can be called upon in an expression as: @created_variable_name.

My main questions:

- Does QGIS allow the creation of project-variables by a plugin?

Although setting up the variables once in the project isn't a major task, it is more user-friendly to have this function and makes is easier to use for beginning users.

- Does QGIS allow a read/write function from a plugin to the projectvariables?
- What is the best book to buy, or tutorial to follow, in creating this plugin?

Comment: Answer of the two first points : yes and yes. For the last one, a good start is : https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins/index.html. And if you have questions, I opened an "issue" on your project.